# PDO database class selection function with prepared where clauses

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to make a PDO database class with prepared statements but I seemed to have gotten my self stuck at the select function. I have tried allot of things but it just would always end up giveing me errors. I am also very sorry about the fact that I am not spesific at what actualy goes wrong.

Current errors:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
> D:\wamp64\www\PDOtest\databaseClassTest.php on line 136
> Notice: Array
> to string conversion in D:\wamp64\www\PDOtest\databaseClassTest.php on
> line 137
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in
> D:\wamp64\www\PDOtest\databaseClassTest.php on line 166

```
<?php

class database {
    private $handler;
    public function __construct($databaseType,$host,$dbname,$username,$password) {
        $this->handler = new PDO("{$databaseType}:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $username, $password);
    }
    public function insert($table, $columnsArrayAndValues) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ("; // Make the first part of the Insert query with the table and (. example "INTERT INTO post (";
        
        $countColums = count($columnsArrayAndValues);//make a variable to hold the amount of colums which the user provides with the array.
        /*
        if the array is 
        
        array(
                        ':message' => $message, 
                        ':user_ID' => $user_ID, 
                        ':board_ID' => $board_ID
        )
        this would return 3 because it has 3 elements
        */
        
        
        $i = 0; //initialize an iterator
        foreach($columnsArrayAndValues  as $colum => $value) { // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $i++; // add one to the iterator
            if($i < $countColums){ //if the Iterator is smallen then the amount of colums
                $sql .= $colum . ", "; // add the colum name to the sql string and add a ,    
                // i do this because when you have multipe colums you need an , to differentiate the colums
            } else {
                $sql .= $colum . ")";// the last ellement should not have an ,!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it should also have an ) at the end of the colum declartion
            }
        }
        $sql .= " VALUES ("; // add the values clause...
        
        $i = 0; // reset the iterator
        foreach($columnsArrayAndValues  as $colum => $value) { // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $i++; // add one to the iterator
            if($i < $countColums){ //if the Iterator is smallen then the amount of colums
                $sql .= ":{$colum}, "; // add the prepared name to the sql string and add a ,  
                // i do this because when you have multipe prepared names you need an , to differentiate the colums
            } else {
                $sql .= ":{$colum})"; /// the last element should not have an ,......
            }
        }
        
        $query = $this->handler->prepare($sql); //prepare the statement
        $ar = array(); //initialize an array
        
        foreach($columnsArrayAndValues  as $colum => $value) { // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $ar[":{$colum}"]= $value; // make the link...
        }
        $query->execute($ar);// execute the query
    }
    
    public function select($fieldAndTableArray, $where = NULL) {
        $sql = "SELECT ";
        $fieldAndTableArray;
        $countTabels = count($fieldAndTableArray);//make a variable to hold the amount of colums which the user provides with the array.
        
        /*
        if the array is 
        
        array(
                "tabel" => array("colum1a", "colum2a", "colum3a", "colum4a"),
                "tabel2" => array("colum1b", "colum2b", "colum3b", "colum4b")
            )
        this would return 2 because it has 2 elements
        */
        foreach($fieldAndTableArray as $table => $fields){ // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $countFields = count($fields);//make a variable to hold the amount of colums which the user provides with the array.
            $i =0;
            foreach($fields as $field) {
                $i++;
                $sql .= "`{$table}`.`{$field}`";
                if($i <= $countFields) {
                    $sql .= ", ";
                }
            }
        }
        $sql .= " FROM ";
        $i = 0;
        foreach($fieldAndTableArray as $table => $fields){ // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $i++;
            $sql .= "`{$table}`";
            if($i < $countTabels) {
                $sql .=", ";
            }
        }
        if($where != NULL) {
            $sql .= " WHERE ";
            if(is_array($where)) {
                foreach($where as $wherePart) {
                    
                    if(is_array($wherePart)) {
                        $elementCounter = 0;
                        foreach($wherePart as $element){
                            $elementCounter++;
                            if($elementCounter >= 3){
                                $sql .= ":{$element}";
                            } else {
                                $sql .= $element . " ";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $sql .= $wherePart . " ";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sql .= $where;
            }
        }

        
        if(is_array($where)) {
            $ar = array(); //initialize an array
            foreach($where as $wherePart=>$value) {
                
                if(is_array($wherePart)) {
                    $elementCounter = 0;
                    foreach($wherePart as $element){
                        $elementCounter++;
                        if($elementCounter >= 3){
                            $ar[":{$colum}"]= $value; // make the link...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        $query = $this->handler->prepare($sql); //prepare the statement
        
        foreach($where  as $colum => $value) { // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $ar[":{$colum}"]= $value; // make the link...
        }
        $query->execute($ar);// execute the query
        return $query->execute($ar);// execute the query
    }   
}


$db = new database("mysql", "127.0.0.1", "imageboard", "root", "");

//$db->insert("post", array("message"=>"Hello i am a message from PDO", "user_ID"=>(int)1, "board_ID"=>(int)2));
/*var_dump($db->select(
        array(
                "tabel" => array("colum1a", "colum2a", "colum3a", "colum4a"),
                "tabel2" => array("colum1b", "colum2b", "colum3b", "colum4b")
            ),
        array(
            array("colum1a", "=", "banaan"), "AND",
            array("colum1b", "!=", "24")
        )
));*/
echo "deze werkt goed->";
$result = $db->select(
        array(
                "post" => array("post_ID", "post_name", "image_ID", "message"),
                "image" => array("image_path")
            ),
        array(
            array("`post`.`image_ID`", "=", "`image`.`image_ID`")
        )
);
var_dump($result);
while($row = $result->fetchAll()) 
{ 
    echo $row['message'].'<br>'; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: If you use a framework like Codeigniter or Zend they do this for you and manage security etc. Saves a lot of dev time.

Comment: But I want to be able to code this my self. Besides I  don't trust other peoples code. This is for a endproject of school this year that does not realy matter though.

Comment: but thanks anyways :3. i do this for practicing. I am making lots of difrent classes so my entire project will be OOP

Comment: @Kevin I agree with your comments in general, above here, but never consider ever writing code that "doesn't really matter", that is the path to sloppy coding and bad habits being formed. Evey bit of code you write (especially when learning) should be as smart and practical as possible, regardless of its actual use. `:-)`

Comment: and which line is line 136?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time looking at the code and came up with this

```
<?php
class Database {
    private static $handler;
    private $db;
    
    protected function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname='  . Config::get('mysql/database'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$handler)) { //if there is no instance jet we want to make an instance one would also use this to excute things methods inside this this class
            self::$handler = new Database();
        }
        return self::$handler; //return the instance
    }
    
    public function insert($table, $columnsArrayAndValues) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` ("; // Make the first part of the Insert query with the table and (. example "INTERT INTO post (";
        
        $countColums = count($columnsArrayAndValues);//make a variable to hold the amount of colums which the user provides with the array.
        /*
        if the array is 
        
        array(
                        ':message' => $message, 
                        ':user_ID' => $user_ID, 
                        ':board_ID' => $board_ID
        )
        this would return 3 because it has 3 elements
        */
        
        
        $i = 0; //initialize an iterator
        foreach($columnsArrayAndValues  as $colum => $value) { // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $i++; // add one to the iterator
            if($i < $countColums){ //if the Iterator is smallen then the amount of colums
                $sql .= "`{$colum}`, "; // add the colum name to the sql string and add a ,    
                // i do this because when you have multipe colums you need an , to differentiate the colums
            } else {
                $sql .= "`{$colum}`)";// the last ellement should not have an ,!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it should also have an ) at the end of the colum declartion
            }
        }
        $sql .= " VALUES ("; // add the values clause...
        
        $i = 0; // reset the iterator
        foreach($columnsArrayAndValues  as $colum => $value) { // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $i++; // add one to the iterator
            if($i < $countColums){ //if the Iterator is smallen then the amount of colums
                $sql .= "?, "; // add the prepared name to the sql string and add a ,  
                // i do this because when you have multipe prepared names you need an , to differentiate the colums
            } else {
                $sql .= "?)"; /// the last element should not have an ,......
            }
        }
        
        $ar = array(); //initialize an array
        
        foreach($columnsArrayAndValues  as $colum => $value) { // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $ar[]= $this->replaceQuotesAndBackslashes($value); // make the link...
        }
        if($this->action($sql, $ar)) {
            return $this->db->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
    public function select($fieldAndTableArray, $where = NULL) {
        $sql = "SELECT ";
        $fieldAndTableArray;
        $countTabels = count($fieldAndTableArray);//make a variable to hold the amount of colums which the user provides with the array.
        
        /*
        if the array is 
        
        array(
                "tabel" => array("colum1a", "colum2a", "colum3a", "colum4a"),
                "tabel2" => array("colum1b", "colum2b", "colum3b", "colum4b")
            )
        this would return 2 because it has 2 elements
        */
        foreach($fieldAndTableArray as $table => $fields){ // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $countFields = count($fields);//make a variable to hold the amount of colums which the user provides with the array.
            $i =0;
            foreach($fields as $field) {
                $i++;
                $sql .= "`{$table}`.`{$field}`";
                if($i <= $countFields) {
                    $sql .= ", ";
                }
            }
        }
        
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
        $sql .= " FROM ";
        $i = 0;
        foreach($fieldAndTableArray as $table => $fields){ // cut the colums array into parts and loop threw them
            $i++;
            $sql .= "`{$table}`";
            if($i < $countTabels) {
                $sql .=", ";
            }
        }
        if($where != NULL) {
            $sql .= " WHERE ";
            foreach($where as $wherePart) {
                
                if(is_array($wherePart)) {
                    $elementCounter = 0;
                    foreach($wherePart as $element){
                        $elementCounter++;
                        if($elementCounter >= 3){
                            $sql .= "?";
                        } else {
                            $sql .= $element . " ";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $sql .= " " . $wherePart . " ";
                }
            }
            $ar = array(); //initialize an array
    
            foreach($where as $wherePart) {
                $elementCounter++;
                if(is_array($wherePart)){
                    $elementCounter = 0;
                    foreach($wherePart as $value) {
                        $elementCounter++;
                        if($elementCounter == 3){
                            $ar[] = $this->replaceQuotesAndBackslashes($value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//      $this->query($query, $ar);
        return $this->query($sql, $ar);
    }
    
    public function query($sql, $params) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql); //prepare the statement
        $query->execute($params);// execute the query
        return $query;
    }
    public function action($sql, $params) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql); //prepare the statement
        return $query->execute($params);// execute the query
    }
    
    private function replaceQuotesAndBackslashes($fieldValue){
//      $fieldValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fieldValue);
        $fieldValue = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $fieldValue);
        $fieldValue = str_replace("'", '\\\'', $fieldValue);
        
        return $fieldValue;
    }
}
/* EXAMPLES AND TESTING


Database::getInstance()->insert(
        "tabelname", array(
    "column1" => $value1,
    "column2" => $value1
));

$result = Database::getInstance()->select(
        array(
                "post" => array("post_ID", "post_name", "image_ID", "message"),
                "image" => array("image_path")
            ),
        array(
            array("`post`.`image_ID`", "=", "1"), "AND",
            array("`post`.`post_ID`", "!=", "34567")
        )
);


while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    echo"<pre>", print_r($row), "<pre />";
}



/*$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT message, post_name
    FROM post
    WHERE post_name < ?');
$sth->execute(array('red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();*/

/*
119470ef20ab9907b293fb36e5200b7c
Kevin Neven 2016 5-6 23:34*/
`
```

Comment: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: Please, never catch an exception you cannot do something useful with. i.e. you need to do some more useful processing with and continue the program. Assume that all the exceptions will be reported to the appropriate people in a live environment. In development and testing then you want 'feedback' quickly. ;-/